# Search combined 2D array values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got a 2D array and Im wondering how to search it using PHP.  My array is:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [Image] => 1.png
        [Manufacturer] => Manu1
        [Model] => Model1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [Image] => 2.png 
        [Manufacturer] => Manu2
        [Model] => Model2
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [Image] => 3.png
        [Manufacturer] => Manu3
        [Model] => Model3
    )
) ]
```

What I want people to be able to do is do a "LIKE" search on the combined value of Manufacturer and Model.  Ie, if someone searched for:

```
Ma = Would return all 
Mo = Would return all 
Manu3 = Would return Manu 3 Model3
Manu2 Mo =Would return Manu 2 Mo'XXXX'
Model1 = Would return Manu 1 Model 1
```

Comment: And what should happen if I search for `png`???

Comment: Probably no result, since he said to search on the combined value of Manufacturer and Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a repaired code from **Jeroen**:

```
function searchArray($query, $array) {
    $tmp = array();
    $subq = explode(' ', $query);
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        foreach($subq as $q) {
            if (strpos($val['Manufacturer'], $q) !== 0 || strpos($val['Model'], $q) !== 0) {
                $tmp[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
    return $tmp;
}

print_r($tmp);
```

Comment: My bad, I read the question wrong; this should work perfectly indeed

Comment: Still not, if the search query is `Manu3 Mo` it will find nothing... We have to parse the query as well... OMG.

Comment: Its basically an array of cars.  So if you search for Civic, it would return Honda Civic.  If you search for Honda, it'd return all Hondas.  Hopefully this makes sense?  Will the code above still work?  The image is just for returning an image for whatever the search finds

Comment: @GregHesp Yep, now it should work. It will return an array whether there is only one result or all Hondas...

Comment: @shadyyx Just had a thought about how the would work.  Is it possible to output the combination of the Manufacturer and Model into 1 variable ($a) and then the Image for that combination into another variable?

Comment: @GregHesp Nope. If You want to output that You will have to output either an array or an object otherwise You can ouptut only one 'simple' variable... And if You should return all Hondas, You can output the result only as array (or more sofisticated ArrayObject or similar)... The only way to do this is to create an encoded JSON array or so and return it as one simple string... What is Your goal - what do You want to achieve?

Comment: @shadyyx Job Done, only just woke up :)

Comment: @K20GH Good morning then. Glad to hear I could help. Have a nice day.